# Cart items are not updating when same product is added multiple time

Tags: magento2, mini-cart

When an item of same type is added to cart more than one, the drop down cart preview still shows "1 item in cart".

[image]

I am working in magento 2. Please help me how to fix this issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not an issue.

In admin panel, there is setting whether you want to display quantity wise or item-wise.

Goto: **Stores -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout -> My Cart Link**
and change the settings accordingly.

[image: My Cart Link]

Comment: I want to show total number of item in drop-down mini-cart. Let say if there are 4 quantities it should show 4 items in cart in minicart dropdown.